# Mule 3.1 - Static web server via jetty?

Tags: java, timeout, mule

I cannot figure out how to use the jetty:endpoint in a Mule 3.1 context.  Examples such as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1430127/mule-jetty-setup) do not work in my context.  The application fails to load after a long period of timeout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mule xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
      xmlns:vm="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/vm"
      xmlns:script="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/scripting"
      xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http"
      xmlns:cxf="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/cxf"
      xmlns:xm="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/xml"
      xmlns:pattern="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/pattern"
      xmlns:servlet="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/servlet"
      xmlns:jetty="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/jetty"
      xmlns:test="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/test"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/3.1/mule.xsd
        http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/3.1/mule-http.xsd
        http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/cxf http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/cxf/3.1/mule-cxf.xsd
        http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/scripting http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/scripting/3.1/mule-scripting.xsd
        http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/pattern http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/pattern/3.1/mule-pattern.xsd
        http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/xml http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/xml/3.1/mule-xml.xsd
        http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/vm http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/vm/3.1/mule-vm.xsd
        http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/servlet http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/servlet/3.1/mule-servlet.xsd
        http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/test http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/test/3.1/mule-test.xsd
        http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/jetty http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/jetty/3.1/mule-jetty.xsd"
        >

    <description>
    </description>

    <jetty:endpoint address="http://localhost:8080" 
                name="jettyEndpoint" 
                host="localhost" 
                port="8080" path="/"/> 
    <model name="Jetty">
    <service name="jettyUMO">
      <inbound>
        <jetty:inbound-endpoint ref="jettyEndpoint" /> 
      </inbound>
      <test:component appendString="Received" /> 
    </service>
    </model>



</mule>
```

Exception:

```
INFO  2011-06-06 16:11:34,248 [main] org.mule.MuleServer: Mule Server initializing...
INFO  2011-06-06 16:11:34,525 [main] org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager: Initialising RegistryBroker
INFO  2011-06-06 16:11:34,580 [main] org.mule.config.spring.MuleApplicationContext: Refreshing org.mule.config.spring.MuleApplicationContext@5b976011: startup date [Mon Jun 06 16:11:34 EDT 2011]; root of context hierarchy
WARN  2011-06-06 16:12:50,714 [main] org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader: Ignored XML validation warning
java.net.ConnectException: Operation timed out
    at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.warning(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.reportSchemaWarning(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.getSchemaDocument1(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.getSchemaDocument(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.parseSchema(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.loadSchema(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.findSchemaGrammar(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.getGlobalElementDecl(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.SubstitutionGroupHandler.getMatchingElemDecl(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.models.XSDFACM.oneTransition(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.handleStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.emptyElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultDocumentLoader.loadDocument(DefaultDocumentLoader.java:75)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:388)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:143)
    at org.mule.config.spring.MuleApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(MuleApplicationContext.java:107)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:130)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:467)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:397)
    at org.mule.config.spring.SpringRegistry.doInitialise(SpringRegistry.java:89)
    at org.mule.registry.AbstractRegistry.initialise(AbstractRegistry.java:107)
    at org.mule.config.spring.SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.createSpringRegistry(SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.java:116)
    at org.mule.config.spring.SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.doConfigure(SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.java:73)
    at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractConfigurationBuilder.java:47)
    at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.java:78)
    at org.mule.config.builders.AutoConfigurationBuilder.autoConfigure(AutoConfigurationBuilder.java:101)
    at org.mule.config.builders.AutoConfigurationBuilder.doConfigure(AutoConfigurationBuilder.java:57)
    at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractConfigurationBuilder.java:47)
    at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.java:78)
    at org.mule.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory.createMuleContext(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:198)
    at org.mule.MuleServer.initialize(MuleServer.java:391)
    at org.mule.MuleServer.run(MuleServer.java:277)
    at org.mule.MuleServer.start(MuleServer.java:264)
    at org.mule.MuleServer.main(MuleServer.java:134)
```

It seems like the error happens when the .xsd is loaded for validation.  But that is a valid URL, so I don't know what I could be doing wrong.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you deploy this configuration in Mule 3.1 standalone?

NB. On an endpoint you should either use @address or @host/@port/@path, but not both.

Comment: Removing the @host @port didn't fix anything, but thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the problem by removing the test:component element.  I don't know why but its presence completely breaks the app.  You can read more detailed solution instructions on my blog: http://developmentality.wordpress.com/2011/06/07/embed-a-jetty-file-server-within-mule-3-1-1/